# Excluding Background from Color Picking

Tags: opengl, color, glut, picking

I've implemented picking based on color coding, but I don't want the background color to be pickable. Is there any way in openGL (2.x) to exclude the background color? For some reason, doing glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) just before rendering in "color picking" mode, excludes the background in windows but not in Linux.

I'm using glut btw.

Answer (score 2):

If you are rendering with one different single color for each pickable item, then just compare the color under the mouse against the background color.